# odbc connection issue.(UNICODE Using encoding ASCII)

Tags: c++, postgresql, unicode, odbc, ascii

I'm trying to connect DB server(postgresql) with two other programs.
one connects well, but the other program can not connect to odbc.
I wonder why that 'UNICODE ~~~ UCS-2LE' line printed.
and how to fix not connected program.

-----------  connection success -------------

```
          [ODBC][164734][1601017650.697151][SQLDriverConnect.c][701]

            Entry:
                    Connection = 0x7031f0
                    Window Hdl = (nil)
                    Str In = [ODBC;DSN=MyPostgres;UID=pgadmin;PWD=***********][length = 50 (SQL_NTS)]
                    Str Out = 0x7ffe23bd3ef0
                    Str Out Max = 1024
                    Str Out Ptr = 0x7ffe23bd3eec
                    Completion = 0
            UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ISO8859-1' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'
            [ODBC][164734][1601017650.703341][SQLDriverConnect.c][1560]
            Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
```

----------- connection fail ------------

```
          [ODBC][164812][1601018015.020875][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]

            Entry:
                    Connection = 0x1c07b30
                    Window Hdl = (nil)
                    Str In = [ODBC;DSN=MyPostgres;UID=pgadmin;PWD=***********][length = 50 (SQL_NTS)]
                    Str Out = 0x7fffd28b6bb0
                    Str Out Max = 1024
                    Str Out Ptr = 0x7fffd28b6bac
                    Completion = 0
                    [ODBC][164812][1601018015.020905][SQLDriverConnect.c][1239]
                    Error: IM002
```

Comment: The Unicode message is printed when you successfully connect so why are you trying to fix that?

Comment: Anyway your connection fails almost certainly because your connections settings are wrong in some way. Without knowing more details about your environment and the method you are using to connect it's difficult to help.

Comment: [See this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1932912.aspx?ERROR+IM002+Microsoft+ODBC+Driver+Manager+Data+source+name+not+found+and+no+default+driver+specified).  I see no C++ code here, but for ODBC errors, you should be calling [SQLGetDiagRec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdiagrec-function?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Comment: thank you very very much. 'SQLGetDiagRec' makes me to fix the problem.